# In a go worker/event system, should workers access the same struct (via pointer) to do work?

Tags: go, events, channel

I'm a beginner gopher, and I wrote an event listener worker queue for a project I'm working on.

I've deployed it on a staging server. After around 100 events have been triggered the listeners stop getting called when events are published. The server hasn't crashed either.

Here is my implementation:

```
// Event struct 
type Event struct {
  Name string
  Data interface{}
}

// Stream to publish events to
var stream = make(chan *Event, 100)

// Publish sends new event data to the stream by the event name
func Publish(name string, data interface{}) {
  ev := &Event{name, data}
  stream <- ev
}

// Handler provides the interface for all event handlers.
// The Work will be called with the event that it should process
type Handler interface {
  Work(*Event)
}

type worker struct {
  Handler
  Listen chan *Event
  Quit   chan bool
}

// Stop shuts down the worker
func (w *worker) Stop() {
  go func() {
    w.Quit <- true
  }()
}

// Queue of worker Listen channels
type workerQueue chan chan *Event

// registry of workers
var registry = make(map[string][]workerQueue)

// Register creates 20 workers, assigns them to a queue, and 
// appends the resulting worker queue to an event on the handler registry
func Register(name string, handlers ...Handler) {
  if _, ok := registry[name]; !ok {
    registry[name] = make([]workerQueue, 0)
  }

  // Create workerQueues for each handler
  for _, h := range handlers {
    queue := make(workerQueue, numListeners)

    // Create 20 workers
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
      newWorker := worker{
        Handler: h,
        Listen:  make(chan *Event),
        Quit:    make(chan bool),
      }

      go func() {
        for {
          select {
          case ev := <-newWorker.Listen:
            nl.Work(ev)
          case <-newWorker.Quit:
            return
          }
        }
      }()

      queue <- newWorker.Listen
    }

    registry[name] = append(registry[name], queue)
  }
}

// Start begins listening for events on stream
func Start() {
  go func() {
    for {
      select {
      // listen for events
      case ev := <-stream:
        go func() {
          // get registered queues for the event
          queues, ok := registry[ev.Name]

          if !ok {
            return
          }

          // Get worker channel from queue and send the event
          for _, queue := range queues {
            worker := <-queue
            worker <- ev
          }
        }()
      }
    }
  }()
}
```

Here is an example usage.

```
// Usage

Start()

type demoHandler struct {
  db *sql.DB
}

type eventData struct {}

func (h *demoHandler) Work(ev *Event) {
  // Do something
  return
}

// Register handler
Register('some-event', &demoHandler{r})

Publish('some-event', &eventData{})
```

I'm passing a pointer to a demoHandler as the event handler because they need access to the underlying sql instance. Is it a problem that each worker queue uses the same demoHandler?

I can't for the life of me figure out where I went wrong! Short of an error in the handler code, is there a mistake in my code which causes all of my workers to go down?

Comment: *"Is it a problem that each worker queue uses the same demoHandler?"* if they are used in a read-only fashion, then no. If you're also writing (ie setting the handler's fields) then you should use a mutex from the `sync` package to avoid possible race conditions.

Comment: After the problem appears, send the process a SIGQUIT to dump the goroutine stacks.  That should help pinpoint where the program is blocked. I suspect that you will find goroutiens blocked on `worker := <-queue`.  I am having trouble understanding the purpose of some of the code.  If you are still stuck, it will be helpful to update the question to describe in words the purpose of the code.

Comment: "Don't communicate by sharing memory, share memory by communicating." I.e., doesn't have multiple goroutines read the same memory, have them notify each other via channels of information that they need.

Answer (score 0):

"In a go worker/event system, should workers access the same struct (via pointer) to do work?"
No, it's not a problem. It would be a problem if the code inside your handler access a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section), but I think that's not causing your program to block.

Your server doesn't crash or block either because no panic is being triggered, and your program is listening and executing on separate goroutines, which are lightweight threads of execution.

It probably has to be with the channels you are using to send and receive events.

Sends and receives to a [channel](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) are blocking by default. This means that when you send or receive from a channel it will block its goroutine until the other side is ready.

In the case of [buffered channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3), sends block when the buffer is full, and receives block when the buffer is empty, as in your stream channel:

```
var stream = make(chan *Event, 100)
```

You said: "After around 100 events have been triggered the listeners stop getting called when events are published".

So if you call the Publish function and do `stream <- ev` when the "stream" channel buffer is full, it will block until the channel has place to receive another element.

I'd suggest reading a bit about [non-blocking channel operations](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations).

Maybe the block is occurring in some part of your real usage code.